Make a shared library self-contained (pre-link dependencies of a shared library into it, recursively)?
I want to package a native shared library into a Java application (so it becomes part of the JAR), to be called via JNI.
The shared library (Linux) comes from a 3rd party and has some dependencies, looking roughly like this:
$ readelf -d libpdalcpp.so.17.0.0
 
Dynamic section at offset 0xd9a4a0 contains 38 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgdal.so.32]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libproj.so.25]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgeotiff.so.5]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libxml2.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 ...

My problem is that I cannot (don't want to) guarantee that these dependencies will be available at runtime; the resulting Java application will run in some JRE container based on some (I don't want to care which) Linux distribution.
So what I want is to resolve these dependencies at build time, and produce from my initial shared library with dependencies on other shared libraries one without any (or with as little as possible) dependencies on other shared libraries from the system.

Can this be achived? Are linkers supporting this kind of operation?
Is the whole idea stupid? (the best answer I got so far was that the principle behind shared libraries is modularity; however, bytecode machines like the JRE (or CLR, or ...) fall into the category where shared libraries are used for plugins, and a plugin usually should be self-contained)


The typical solution is that you bundle the dependent libraries as separate files and fiddle with the library RPATH to make it look in the library's directory. You have to write code to extract the library from the JAR file anyway, so a few more won't break the bank.

My problem is that I cannot (don't want to) guarantee that these dependencies will be available at runtime  You have to - if they're not available, your library won't load and if you try to keep running your code will do nothing but toss exception after exception.  @Botje above has provided one way to do that, but even that doesn't guarantee the libraries you bundle are compatible with the platform the user is trying to run them on.

@Andrew Henle that's the point; consider Docker/Snap/Flatpak, they get away by just bundling all binary dependencies at packaging time, so the remaining dependency is the system calls to the OS kernel (whose API is usually is quite stable, while also not 100.0%). It should be possible to do the same at shared-library level - such that the resulting library wont depend on 3rd party libraries and wont throw exceptions if not present.

If you want to make sure that everything is available inside your shared library, look at static linking. Otherwise you have to either pack everything inside your package (as mentioned already) or require certain packages to be installed.

@Botje and @Oo.oO thanks, I think both is helpful for small dependencies; the problem with RPATH is that one has to track all dependencies manually, so it does not scale well when there are many (or nested) dependencies; the problem with static libraries is that they just declare external symbols, leaving it to the final consumer to ensure that all is there. I come to believe JNI is not very portable ;-)

"track all dependencies manually"? ldd gives you the full set of libraries you need to bundle since it's just a printing addon for the dynamic linker. It's the core of exodus too. Not sure what you mean by "JNI is not very portable", as bundling dependencies like this is a solved problem.

@Botje hey thanks for mentioning exodus, I did not know it (and neither that ldd actually works recursively); exodus seems to be very comfortable (does things automatically, out-of-the-box). what I usually worry about is manual maintenance where I had to read ldd output and had to maintain build configuration by hand... the PDAL library mentioned in the OP is like a swiss army knife, it has lots of direct and transient dependencies; if that can't be circumvented or automated, I decide not to do use JNI. Looks like both ldd and exodus work great but neither provides that automation for JNI.

Why do you ascribe this problem to JNI? You would face the same challenges if you were shipping a plain binary: either all dependencies are already available and you're done, or you  have to figure out the transitive closure of dependencies, transport it, and telll the target program where to load them from.


So what I want is to resolve these dependencies at build time, and convert my initial shared library with dependencies on other shared libraries into one without any

That is impossible in practice: almost all UNIX systems consider the shared library a final link product, which can't be meaningfully modified (except in a very limited number of ways).
Update:

if you know a technical reason why "That is impossible"

The short explanation for why that's impossible (or at least hard) is that the information needed to relink two DSOs into one (in particular the relocation records) has been discarded during the original DSO linking process.
The longer explanation is that a DSO can only have a single procedure linkage table (PLT, read more on PLT here). So you would need to merge two separate PLTs into one. That sounds easy enough -- they are just flat tables.
However, (at least part of) this merged PLT will have to be at a different address from where the original PLTs were. And you would need to update all calls into PLT with the new addresses.
How are you going to find all the addresses that need updating? In the original link, the linker used relocation records in the individual .o files to know which address to set to which slot in a PLT. These records are now gone (AIX is the only UNIX variant I know of which retains relocation records in the linked DSO).
The linker would have to disassemble the two DSOs, and reconstruct these relocation records. Unfortunately, disassembling variable-length instruction sets (such as x86_64) is hard. A general solution requires complete control flow analysis.

I have changed the wording in the OP, "So what I want is to resolve these dependencies at build time, and ~~convert~~ produce from my initial shared library with dependencies on other shared libraries ~~into~~ one without any". If at runtime the dynamic loader can resolve dynamic dependencies, then maybe a linker could do the same at link time (or re-link time in my case). I have not found a linker with that functionality implemented so far, but I suspect it should be possible, technically... if you know a technical reason why "That is impossible", can you add that in your answer?

@ChristianFuchs I've updated the answer.

thanks so far, I was not aware of and have to catch up on PLTs...

Ok, I am happy with that answer; also a bit sad that ;-) Thanks for directing me to the PLT thing! (For anyone else, I found some more details in this article.)
